# Trying to get optgroup tag to appear in Django admin inline

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Here's what I have so far which I thought would work, but I'm getting this error:

```
Template error

In template /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html, error at line 50
Caught TypeError while rendering: render_option() takes exactly 4 arguments (23 given)
40            {% endspaceless %}
41          </td>
42          {% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}
43            {% for line in fieldset %}
44              {% for field in line %}
45                <td class="{{ field.field.name }}">
46                {% if field.is_readonly %}
47                    <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
48                {% else %}
49                    {{ field.field.errors.as_ul }}
50                    {{ field.field }}  <--- error here
```

The code in admin.py

```
def get_construct_choices():
    construct_request_choices = Construct.objects.all().order_by('family','promotor','additional_mutation')
    construct_request_choices = itertools.groupby(construct_request_choices, key=lambda x:str(x.family))
    choices = []
    for family, group in construct_request_choices:
        choices.append((family, [str(val) for val in group]))
    print choices
    return choices

class ConstructRequestCustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ConstructRequest
    construct = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_construct_choices())

class ConstructRequestInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ConstructRequest
    form = ConstructRequestCustomForm
    extra = 1

class RequestAdmin(make_DefaultAdminAuditTable(Request)):
    inlines = (ConstructRequestInline,)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using named groups for [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices), the second element for each group should be an iterable of 2-tuples. The example in the docs is:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('Audio', (
            ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
            ('cd', 'CD'),
        )
    ),
    ('Video', (
            ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
            ('dvd', 'DVD'),
        )
    ),
    ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
)
```

In your code, you are doing

```
    choices.append((family, [str(val) for val in group]))
```

so it looks like the 2nd element is a list of strings, not a list of 2-tuples. It might work if you do

```
    choices.append((family, [(str(val), str(val)) for val in group]))
```

or you might want to change it slightly if you want the display value to be different from the value stored in the database.

Finally, because `get_construct_choices` accesses the database, it would be better to set the choices in the form's `__init__` method. Otherwise, the choices will be loaded when the code loads, but will not update.

```
class ConstructRequestCustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ConstructRequest

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConstructRequestCustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['construct'].choices = get_construct_choices()
```